# How to set two image and text in same line

Tags: html, css

I have a simple problem, how I could set image and text in a single line. like this `[image - text - image]` and so on

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
    <h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` and `<h1>` are block elements by default. So they will display their content on their own line.

So you need to use the `display` property. And set its value to `inline`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        img {
            display: inline;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        h1 {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
    <h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Read more about it here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Thanks soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also but you need to add div because if use display: table-cell means parent class must to use display:table

```html
 <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <style>
        div { display : table }
        div img { display : table-cell }
        div h1 { display : table-cell }
        img {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
        <h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
        <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways is there you can add class for image and h1 and use float (but float old method and if you use this you want clear also so better use display) and another way you can use display:inline-block
example:

```
<body>
<img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" class="img">
<h1 class="txt">afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
<img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" class="img">
```

Css:

```
img{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
txt{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display:inline` for a single line output:

```
img,h1 {display:inline;}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two possible solutions:

### 1st - Inline Block

Just add a class with inline-block and that will do the trick.

**CSS**

```
.inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**
    
    afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf

### 2nd - Float left

You can float all the items to the same direction and you will get *almost* the same result. The thing with floats is that you would like to contain them inside a `display: table` in order prevent other items to go below the floated items.

**CSS**

```
.pull-left{
  float: left;
}

.row{
  display: table;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="pull-left" src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
  <h1 class="pull-left">afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
  <img class="pull-left" src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
</div>
```

#### The difference

You will see in [my live example](https://jsfiddle.net/g5e2udtb/) that both solutions achieve what you want, but the difference is the space between the last two images.

The Float solution remove that space between images.

Both solutions are good, but in your case, I would prefer the 1st one so I dont have to add the `div class="row"`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use list to do that
Html

```
<ul>
    <li><img .....></li>
    <li><h1></h1>
    <li><img .....></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
li{display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  display: inline;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
<h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1>
<img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
```

You need to make the img and h1 in a single line.
Doing like this will effect all your images and h1, so it is better to use `class` or `id` to make it `inline`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        z-index=1;
        margin:0px auto;
        position:asolute;
      }
   ul li{
        float:left;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul><li><img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg"></li>
    <li><h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1></li>
    <li><img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg"></li></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```